# Parsear URL con Python y que el índice se sume

Tags: python

tengo lo siguiente:

```
    URL=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/1
    drt = URL.path.strip('/').split('/')
out: 1
    def WikiIndex(start_value, end_value):
     start_value (int)
     end_value(int)
     drt = URL.path.strip('/').split('/')
     while start_value > end_value:
        print URL.content
```

Y funciona (puede que haya algún error al copiar el código), pero lo que ocurre, evidentemente es que imprime el 'content' de la misma web todo el rato (URL=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/1) y yo lo que necesito es que imprima, pongamos en un diccionario o una lista el 'content' de esta manera (URL=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/1, URL=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/2, ... URL=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/n) según los valores en start y end.
Gracias.

Comment: por lo que parece ser `URL` no es un string. Podrías colocar un código el cual podamos ejecutar y ver el error que mencionas?

Comment: Primero hay que saber Python; el código que publicas no es Python.

Comment: Lo que ocurre Christian es que no puedo escribir la función porque no sé cómo dejar indicado que tiene que ir sumando 1 al final de la URL.

Comment: Deberías repasar el Tutorial de Python: https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Para parsear una URL en Python y generar una lista de URLs con índices consecutivos, puedes utilizar el módulo "urllib" de Python. La idea es crear una función que reciba como parámetros el valor inicial y final del índice, y que genere una lista de URLs con esos índices.

Por ejemplo, podrías utilizar la siguiente función:

```
import urllib

def parse_urls(start_value, end_value):
  # Creamos una lista vacía donde guardaremos las URLs generadas
  urls = []
  # Generamos las URLs con los índices especificados
  for i in range(start_value, end_value + 1):
    # Creamos la URL base
    base_url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
    # Añadimos el índice correspondiente
    url = base_url + str(i)
    # Añadimos la URL a la lista
    urls.append(url)
  # Devolvemos la lista de URLs generadas
  return urls

# Creamos una variable con el valor inicial y final del índice
start_value = 1
end_value = 5

# Llamamos a la función pasándole los valores iniciales y finales
urls = parse_urls(start_value, end_value)

# Imprimimos las URLs generadas
for url in urls:
  print(url)
```

En este caso, la función "parse_urls" recibe dos parámetros: el valor inicial y final del índice. Luego, se agrega un bucle que recorre la lista de URLs generadas y descarga el contenido de cada una de ellas. Luego, se imprime el contenido descargado en pantalla.

Si ejecutas el código anterior, deberías ver que se descargan y muestran en pantalla el contenido de cada una de las URLs generadas.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema que tienes. Si necesitas más ayuda, no dudes en preguntar.